# JVM options using Leiningen

Tags: clojure, leiningen

How do I set JVM options like `-server` when I launch Clojure using Leiningen?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Looking at the [sample.project.clj](http://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj) file on the github repository, It looks like you can pass JVM arguments using the `:jvm-opts` keyword. For Example:

```
:jvm-opts ["-Xmx1g" "-server"]
```

Comment: I just tried it, and it looks like each option should be a separate entry in the vector so: :jvm-opts ["-Xmx1g" "-server"]

Comment: any idea why `:jvm-opts ["--illegal-access=permit"]` doesn't silence the respective warnings (on v11)?