# Leiningen project program can't output non-ASCII string in Windows

Tags: encoding, clojure

I'm working with Clojure code in Windows.

If I directly use Clojure's jar file, it outputs a non-ASCII (Japanese) string without problems.

#### hello.clj:

```
(println "こんにちは")

> java -jar 1.5.1.jar hello.clj
こんにちは
```

But in the case of a Leiningen project, it doesn't output the characters as expected.

#### src/hello/core.clj:

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (println "こんにちは"))

> lein run
????????
```

In both cases, the encoding of the source files is `UTF-8`, the class of `*out*` is `java.io.OutputStreamWriter`, and its encoding is `MS932` (code page for Japanese).

```
(println "*out* :" (class *out*) (.getEncoding *out*))
;; *out* : java.io.OutputStreamWriter MS932
```

I know it will work correctly if I set the environment variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` and use a terminal that supports UTF-8.

But I want to output with `MS932` in Windows' default console, as in the jar file case.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem... it seems strange that running `(println *out* (class *out*) (.getEncoding *out*))` using Leiningen would give you the same results as running it directly using the Clojure jar file, if one of them returns `こんにちは` and the other returns `????????`. It seems like there is an issue with Leiningen's default encoding in Windows, but I would think that running `(.getEncoding *out*)` from Leiningen in your environment would give you something other than MS932, otherwise I don't see why it wouldn't print Japanese characters in a Windows terminal...

There have been issues before with Leiningen preview builds and character encoding doing unexpected things... see [this issue from 2012](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/586) -- although it may have been OS X specific (and a much older version of Leiningen), the issue was that JVM's default encoding was not set to UTF-8. I believe UTF-8 is the default now, but maybe in some Windows environments you need MS932 instead. I don't use Windows, so this is just a shot in the dark, but...

It would appear that the environment variable `LEIN_JVM_OPTS` needs to be set to `-Dfile.encoding=MS932`. See [this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757223/jvm-options-using-leiningen) about setting Leiningen JVM options on a per-project basis. Try adding this line to your project.clj:

```
:jvm-opts ["-Dfile.encoding" "MS932"]
```

If that works, then you might consider adding it under to your `:user` entry in [profiles.clj](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PROFILES.md), i.e.:

```
{:user {:jvm-opts ["-Dfile.encoding" "MS932"]}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried them, but the results was unchanged.

I added `:jvm-opts ["-Dfile.encoding" "MS932"]` to a project.clj, but that didn't work by an error.
I wondered `:jvm-opts ["-Dfile.encoding=MS932"]`. I modified the project.clj, and tried again. the result of output stay "????????".
So I set directly the environment variable `LEIN_JVM_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=MS932`, but the result was same.