# with cloure lein ring server, how to set max heapsize when starting the web appication?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, ring

So when I start the cloure web application with the command lein ring server, there are 2 processed that get started.[image]

The first process is clojur.main that then runs the main web application. The jvm options

```
:jvm-opts ["-Xmx128m"  "-server"]
```

for ring work to control the memory for the web application. The issue is that the **clojure.main -m leingen.core.main** allocates 300+ MB of heap space. (see screenshot 32)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other way is to create a uberjar:

```
> lein clean
> lein uberjar
Compiling demo.hello
Compiling demo.numbers
Created /home/alan/expr/demo-horizon/target/demo-horizon-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Created /home/alan/expr/demo-horizon/target/demo-horizon-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
```

You normally always want to use the `xxx-standalone.jar` version.

Then you start the process using plain java w/o any lein at all:

```
java -jar /home/alan/expr/demo-horizon/target/demo-horizon-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
```

and you can add any flags like `-Xmx4g` or whatever else you like.

---

### Update

I always run `lein clean` before creating a uberjar.  This is the default behavior, but can be disabled by setting `:auto-clean false` in `project.clj`.  According the the Sample project.clj:

```
  ; By default Leiningen will run a clean before creating jars to prevent
  ; undeclared AOT from leaking to downstream consumers; this disables
  ; that behaviour.
  :auto-clean false
```

I cannot see why starting with a dirty build would ever be a good idea, which is why I always manually run `lein clean` first (just in case `:auto-clean` has been disabled).

Comment: `lein-ring` [suggests that you use `lein ring uberjar`](https://github.com/weavejester/lein-ring#executable-jar-files) rather than just `lein uberjar`. It does mostly the same thing but sets `:auto-clean false`, whatever that means.

Answer (score 2):

well never mind

apparently I should run 
lein ***trampoline*** ring server

This way leingen gets out of the way , saving memory

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `:jvm-opts` in your `project.clj`. e.g.

```clj
:jvm-opts ["-Xmx1g" "-server"]
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757223/jvm-options-using-leiningen)

Comment: Don't you mean `project.clj`? I think he already tried that as described in the post.